# How to add retina images to svn

Tags: iphone, ios, svn

I need to help for you.

I made images for retina display like "****@2x.png".
but it can not add to svn like this.

```
******-no-iMac-2:baz shunter$ svn add retina_images/foo@2x.png
svn: warning: 'retina_images/foo' not found
```

I know how to add resource each like this.

```
******-no-iMac-2:baz shunter$ svn add retina_images/foo@2x.png@
A  (bin)  retina_images/foo@2x.png
```

but I made many images, so I feel so bad to do this way.

I really want to know how to add like this.

```
******-no-iMac-2:baz shunter$ svn add retina_images/bar/*.png
```

Please help!!

Comment: You're correct. But I could'nt found it.

Comment: Click on your name (or go to http://stackoverflow.com/users/366052/shunter1112) and there's a list of all your questions.

Answer (score 23):

http://developers.enormego.com/view/add_2x_ios4_resources_svn

This is due to internal path recognizers in SVN. It expects the last at symbol to specify a revision. This is easily corrected by adding an at symbol to the end of your file:

```
$ svn add Default@2x.png@
A (bin) Default@2x.png
```

By Shuan (not me:)

Answer (score 19):

The `svn` command interprets the `@` as an attempt to specify an SVN revision number (@REV format), so...

**To add a single file:**

```
svn add filename@2x.png@
```

Now `svn` sees the final `@` as the @REV specifier instead of the first one.

**To add multiple files:** (each with the @ symbol added to the end of the file-name)

```
ls *2x.png | xargs -I x svn add x@
```

This lists `*2x.png` which will list all your retina images (in the current directory) and the output goes through `xargs`, which executes the `svn add` command for each file. The `-I x` tells `xargs` to replace 'x' with the file-name, so `svn add x@` becomes the correct file-name with the '@' symbol added to the end.

Comment: Thanks for a proper answer with the explanation included. This is how all answers should be

Answer (score 7):

I had this exact problem a few days ago and solved it this way:

```
berry$ for i in retina_images/bar/*.png
do
   svn add $i@
done

A  (bin)  retina_images/bar/foo1@2x.png
A  (bin)  retina_images/bar/foo2@2x.png
A  (bin)  retina_images/bar/foo3@2x.png
A  (bin)  retina_images/bar/foo4@2x.png

berry$ svn commit
```

It's not, perhaps, an ideal solution to the problem, but it worked and I could move on.

Answer (score 5):

I did it like this (in terminal)

```
svn add Images/icon@2x.png@
```

**Or**

The best way is go to `Xcode`, right click on the `image>source control add`. It adds the images without showing any error.

Comment: Your first answer is explicitly mentioned in the question. As for Xcode, it isn't said that Xcode is used or an option.

Answer (score 3):

Do it like this much easier...

Example:

```
svn add default@2x.png@2x
```

Comment: Why do you append `@2x` at the end? `@` is sufficient

Answer (score 3):

This question is a bit old now but I notice nobody had yet posted a truly easy one-liner for adding, via terminal, ALL new image files, regardless of extension or "@2x" status - or for removing them. I have these lines in my bash_profile:

```
alias svn_addall="svn st | grep '^?' | sed -e 's/@2x.*/&@/' | awk '{print \$2}' | xargs svn add"
alias svn_delall="svn st | grep '^\!' | sed -e 's/@2x.*/&@/' | awk '{print \$2}' | xargs svn rm"
```

Then if you run `svn_addall` from any subfolder in your project, it will add ALL files, recursively, whether or not they have @2x in the name.

e.g. all of the below would be added in one go:

```
?       header_bar.png
?       bg@2x.jpg
?       bg.jpg
?       header_bar@2x.png
```

`svn_delall`, in the same way, removes all those pesky `!`-marked files that you've deleted via Finder but not yet from svn ;)

Note, these are modified a bit from other people's scripts I've found online, but the others were always either png specific (what about `@2x.jpg`?), or they only add retina files without also adding other missing "normal" image files.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I have found is through Subversion integration within XCode. Once you have SVN integration setup (XCode>SCM>Configure SCM), Command+click on the item in the Groups & Files window and choose "Add to Repository". To delete an item, hit delete and choose select YES when prompted if you want to remove from source control.